# LINQ to SQLite Gives Parser Stack Overflow Error

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sqlite, linq-to-entities

I finally managed to get SQLite running with C# LINQ to Entities, and also to use User Defined Functions. It works for some queries but throws errors for other queries.

Here the log of the queries that fail.

This first query returns "stack overflow error".

```
SELECT 
[Project27].[MediaTypeId] AS [MediaTypeId], 
[Project27].[MediaId] AS [MediaId], 
[Project27].[Artist] AS [Artist], 
[Project27].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Project27].[Album] AS [Album], 
[Project27].[MediaCategoryId] AS [MediaCategoryId], 
[Project27].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
[Project27].[Preference] AS [Preference], 
[Project27].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project27].[C2] AS [C2], 
[Project27].[BuyUrl] AS [BuyUrl], 
[Project27].[C5] AS [C3], 
[Project27].[C6] AS [C4], 
[Project27].[C7] AS [C5], 
[Project27].[C8] AS [C6], 
[Project27].[C9] AS [C7], 
[Project27].[C10] AS [C8], 
[Project27].[C11] AS [C9], 
[Project27].[C12] AS [C10], 
[Project27].[C3] AS [C11], 
[Project27].[C4] AS [C12]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Project26].[MediaId] AS [MediaId], 
    [Project26].[MediaTypeId] AS [MediaTypeId], 
    [Project26].[Artist] AS [Artist], 
    [Project26].[Title] AS [Title], 
    [Project26].[Album] AS [Album], 
    [Project26].[MediaCategoryId] AS [MediaCategoryId], 
    [Project26].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
    [Project26].[Preference] AS [Preference], 
    [Project26].[BuyUrl] AS [BuyUrl], 
    [Project26].[Length] AS [C1], 
    CASE WHEN ('' <> [Project26].[DownloadUrl]) THEN 1 WHEN ('' = [Project26].[DownloadUrl]) THEN 0 END AS [C2], 
    CASE WHEN ((@p__linq__9 IS NULL) OR ((LENGTH(@p__linq__9)) = 0)) THEN NULL ELSE [Project26].[C9] END AS [C3], 
    1 AS [C4], 
    [Project26].[C1] AS [C5], 
    [Project26].[C2] AS [C6], 
    [Project26].[C3] AS [C7], 
    [Project26].[C4] AS [C8], 
    [Project26].[C5] AS [C9], 
    [Project26].[C6] AS [C10], 
    [Project26].[C7] AS [C11], 
    [Project26].[C8] AS [C12]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Project24].[MediaId] AS [MediaId], 
        [Project24].[MediaTypeId] AS [MediaTypeId], 
        [Project24].[Artist] AS [Artist], 
        [Project24].[Title] AS [Title], 
        [Project24].[Album] AS [Album], 
        [Project24].[MediaCategoryId] AS [MediaCategoryId], 
        [Project24].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
        [Project24].[Preference] AS [Preference], 
        [Project24].[Length] AS [Length], 
        [Project24].[DownloadUrl] AS [DownloadUrl], 
        [Project24].[BuyUrl] AS [BuyUrl], 
        [Project24].[C1] AS [C1], 
        [Project24].[C2] AS [C2], 
        [Project24].[C3] AS [C3], 
        [Project24].[C4] AS [C4], 
        [Project24].[C5] AS [C5], 
        [Project24].[C6] AS [C6], 
        [Project24].[C7] AS [C7], 
        [Project24].[C8] AS [C8], 
        (SELECT 
            [DbGetRatingValue]([Extent18].[Height], [Extent18].[Depth], @p__linq__11) AS [C1]
            FROM  [MediaRatings] AS [Extent18]
            INNER JOIN [RatingCategories] AS [Extent19] ON [Extent18].[RatingId] = [Extent19].[RatingId]
            WHERE (([Project24].[MediaId] = [Extent18].[MediaId]) AND (([Extent19].[Name] = @p__linq__10) OR (1 = 0))) AND ([Extent19].[Custom] = 1) LIMIT 1) AS [C9]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Project23].[MediaId] AS [MediaId], 
            [Project23].[MediaTypeId] AS [MediaTypeId], 
            [Project23].[Artist] AS [Artist], 
            [Project23].[Title] AS [Title], 
            [Project23].[Album] AS [Album], 
            [Project23].[MediaCategoryId] AS [MediaCategoryId], 
            [Project23].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
            [Project23].[Preference] AS [Preference], 
            [Project23].[Length] AS [Length], 
            [Project23].[DownloadUrl] AS [DownloadUrl], 
            [Project23].[BuyUrl] AS [BuyUrl], 
            [Project23].[C1] AS [C1], 
            [Project23].[C2] AS [C2], 
            [Project23].[C3] AS [C3], 
            [Project23].[C4] AS [C4], 
            [Project23].[C5] AS [C5], 
            [Project23].[C6] AS [C6], 
            [Project23].[C7] AS [C7], 
            [Project23].[C8] AS [C8]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Project21].[MediaId] AS [MediaId], 
                [Project21].[MediaTypeId] AS [MediaTypeId], 
                [Project21].[Artist] AS [Artist], 
                [Project21].[Title] AS [Title], 
                [Project21].[Album] AS [Album], 
                [Project21].[MediaCategoryId] AS [MediaCategoryId], 
                [Project21].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
                [Project21].[Preference] AS [Preference], 
                [Project21].[Length] AS [Length], 
                [Project21].[DownloadUrl] AS [DownloadUrl], 
                [Project21].[BuyUrl] AS [BuyUrl], 
                [Project21].[C1] AS [C1], 
                [Project21].[C2] AS [C2], 
                [Project21].[C3] AS [C3], 
                [Project21].[C4] AS [C4], 
                [Project21].[C5] AS [C5], 
                [Project21].[C6] AS [C6], 
                [Project21].[C7] AS [C7], 
                (SELECT 
                    [DbGetRatingValue]([Extent16].[Height], [Extent16].[Depth], @p__linq__8) AS [C1]
                    FROM  [MediaRatings] AS [Extent16]
                    INNER JOIN [RatingCategories] AS [Extent17] ON [Extent16].[RatingId] = [Extent17].[RatingId]
                    WHERE ([Project21].[MediaId] = [Extent16].[MediaId]) AND ('Egoless' = [Extent17].[Name]) LIMIT 1) AS [C8]
                FROM ( SELECT 
                    [Project20].[MediaId] AS [MediaId], 
                    [Project20].[MediaTypeId] AS [MediaTypeId], 
                    [Project20].[Artist] AS [Artist], 
                    [Project20].[Title] AS [Title], 
                    [Project20].[Album] AS [Album], 
                    [Project20].[MediaCategoryId] AS [MediaCategoryId], 
                    [Project20].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
                    [Project20].[Preference] AS [Preference], 
                    [Project20].[Length] AS [Length], 
                    [Project20].[DownloadUrl] AS [DownloadUrl], 
                    [Project20].[BuyUrl] AS [BuyUrl], 
                    [Project20].[C1] AS [C1], 
                    [Project20].[C2] AS [C2], 
                    [Project20].[C3] AS [C3], 
                    [Project20].[C4] AS [C4], 
                    [Project20].[C5] AS [C5], 
                    [Project20].[C6] AS [C6], 
                    [Project20].[C7] AS [C7]
                    FROM ( SELECT 
                        [Project18].[MediaId] AS [MediaId], 
                        [Project18].[MediaTypeId] AS [MediaTypeId], 
                        [Project18].[Artist] AS [Artist], 
                        [Project18].[Title] AS [Title], 
                        [Project18].[Album] AS [Album], 
                        [Project18].[MediaCategoryId] AS [MediaCategoryId], 
                        [Project18].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
                        [Project18].[Preference] AS [Preference], 
                        [Project18].[Length] AS [Length], 
                        [Project18].[DownloadUrl] AS [DownloadUrl], 
                        [Project18].[BuyUrl] AS [BuyUrl], 
                        [Project18].[C1] AS [C1], 
                        [Project18].[C2] AS [C2], 
                        [Project18].[C3] AS [C3], 
                        [Project18].[C4] AS [C4], 
                        [Project18].[C5] AS [C5], 
                        [Project18].[C6] AS [C6], 
                        (SELECT 
                            [DbGetRatingValue]([Extent14].[Height], [Extent14].[Depth], @p__linq__7) AS [C1]
                            FROM  [MediaRatings] AS [Extent14]
                            INNER JOIN [RatingCategories] AS [Extent15] ON [Extent14].[RatingId] = [Extent15].[RatingId]
                            WHERE ([Project18].[MediaId] = [Extent14].[MediaId]) AND ('Love' = [Extent15].[Name]) LIMIT 1) AS [C7]
                        FROM ( SELECT 
                            [Project17].[MediaId] AS [MediaId], 
                            [Project17].[MediaTypeId] AS [MediaTypeId], 
                            [Project17].[Artist] AS [Artist], 
                            [Project17].[Title] AS [Title], 
                            [Project17].[Album] AS [Album], 
                            [Project17].[MediaCategoryId] AS [MediaCategoryId], 
                            [Project17].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
                            [Project17].[Preference] AS [Preference], 
                            [Project17].[Length] AS [Length], 
                            [Project17].[DownloadUrl] AS [DownloadUrl], 
                            [Project17].[BuyUrl] AS [BuyUrl], 
                            [Project17].[C1] AS [C1], 
                            [Project17].[C2] AS [C2], 
                            [Project17].[C3] AS [C3], 
                            [Project17].[C4] AS [C4], 
                            [Project17].[C5] AS [C5], 
                            [Project17].[C6] AS [C6]
                            FROM ( SELECT 
                                [Project15].[MediaId] AS [MediaId], 
                                [Project15].[MediaTypeId] AS [MediaTypeId], 
                                [Project15].[Artist] AS [Artist], 
                                [Project15].[Title] AS [Title], 
                                [Project15].[Album] AS [Album], 
                                [Project15].[MediaCategoryId] AS [MediaCategoryId], 
                                [Project15].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
                                [Project15].[Preference] AS [Preference], 
                                [Project15].[Length] AS [Length], 
                                [Project15].[DownloadUrl] AS [DownloadUrl], 
                                [Project15].[BuyUrl] AS [BuyUrl], 
                                [Project15].[C1] AS [C1], 
                                [Project15].[C2] AS [C2], 
                                [Project15].[C3] AS [C3], 
                                [Project15].[C4] AS [C4], 
                                [Project15].[C5] AS [C5], 
                                (SELECT 
                                    [DbGetRatingValue]([Extent12].[Height], [Extent12].[Depth], @p__linq__6) AS [C1]
                                    FROM  [MediaRatings] AS [Extent12]
                                    INNER JOIN [RatingCategories] AS [Extent13] ON [Extent12].[RatingId] = [Extent13].[RatingId]
                                    WHERE ([Project15].[MediaId] = [Extent12].[MediaId]) AND ('Spiritual Feminine' = [Extent13].[Name]) LIMIT 1) AS [C6]
                                FROM ( SELECT 
                                    [Project14].[MediaId] AS [MediaId], 
                                    [Project14].[MediaTypeId] AS [MediaTypeId], 
                                    [Project14].[Artist] AS [Artist], 
                                    [Project14].[Title] AS [Title], 
                                    [Project14].[Album] AS [Album], 
                                    [Project14].[MediaCategoryId] AS [MediaCategoryId], 
                                    [Project14].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
                                    [Project14].[Preference] AS [Preference], 
                                    [Project14].[Length] AS [Length], 
                                    [Project14].[DownloadUrl] AS [DownloadUrl], 
                                    [Project14].[BuyUrl] AS [BuyUrl], 
                                    [Project14].[C1] AS [C1], 
                                    [Project14].[C2] AS [C2], 
                                    [Project14].[C3] AS [C3], 
                                    [Project14].[C4] AS [C4], 
                                    [Project14].[C5] AS [C5]
                                    FROM ( SELECT 
                                        [Project12].[MediaId] AS [MediaId], 
                                        [Project12].[MediaTypeId] AS [MediaTypeId], 
                                        [Project12].[Artist] AS [Artist], 
                                        [Project12].[Title] AS [Title], 
                                        [Project12].[Album] AS [Album], 
                                        [Project12].[MediaCategoryId] AS [MediaCategoryId], 
                                        [Project12].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
                                        [Project12].[Preference] AS [Preference], 
                                        [Project12].[Length] AS [Length], 
                                        [Project12].[DownloadUrl] AS [DownloadUrl], 
                                        [Project12].[BuyUrl] AS [BuyUrl], 
                                        [Project12].[C1] AS [C1], 
                                        [Project12].[C2] AS [C2], 
                                        [Project12].[C3] AS [C3], 
                                        [Project12].[C4] AS [C4], 
                                        (SELECT 
                                            [DbGetRatingValue]([Extent10].[Height], [Extent10].[Depth], @p__linq__5) AS [C1]
                                            FROM  [MediaRatings] AS [Extent10]
                                            INNER JOIN [RatingCategories] AS [Extent11] ON [Extent10].[RatingId] = [Extent11].[RatingId]
                                            WHERE ([Project12].[MediaId] = [Extent10].[MediaId]) AND ('Spiritual Masculine' = [Extent11].[Name]) LIMIT 1) AS [C5]
                                        FROM ( SELECT 
                                            [Project11].[MediaId] AS [MediaId], 
                                            [Project11].[MediaTypeId] AS [MediaTypeId], 
                                            [Project11].[Artist] AS [Artist], 
                                            [Project11].[Title] AS [Title], 
                                            [Project11].[Album] AS [Album], 
                                            [Project11].[MediaCategoryId] AS [MediaCategoryId], 
                                            [Project11].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
                                            [Project11].[Preference] AS [Preference], 
                                            [Project11].[Length] AS [Length], 
                                            [Project11].[DownloadUrl] AS [DownloadUrl], 
                                            [Project11].[BuyUrl] AS [BuyUrl], 
                                            [Project11].[C1] AS [C1], 
                                            [Project11].[C2] AS [C2], 
                                            [Project11].[C3] AS [C3], 
                                            [Project11].[C4] AS [C4]
                                            FROM ( SELECT 
                                                [Project9].[MediaId] AS [MediaId], 
                                                [Project9].[MediaTypeId] AS [MediaTypeId], 
                                                [Project9].[Artist] AS [Artist], 
                                                [Project9].[Title] AS [Title], 
                                                [Project9].[Album] AS [Album], 
                                                [Project9].[MediaCategoryId] AS [MediaCategoryId], 
                                                [Project9].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
                                                [Project9].[Preference] AS [Preference], 
                                                [Project9].[Length] AS [Length], 
                                                [Project9].[DownloadUrl] AS [DownloadUrl], 
                                                [Project9].[BuyUrl] AS [BuyUrl], 
                                                [Project9].[C1] AS [C1], 
                                                [Project9].[C2] AS [C2], 
                                                [Project9].[C3] AS [C3], 
                                                (SELECT 
                                                    [DbGetRatingValue]([Extent8].[Height], [Extent8].[Depth], @p__linq__4) AS [C1]
                                                    FROM  [MediaRatings] AS [Extent8]
                                                    INNER JOIN [RatingCategories] AS [Extent9] ON [Extent8].[RatingId] = [Extent9].[RatingId]
                                                    WHERE ([Project9].[MediaId] = [Extent8].[MediaId]) AND ('Emotional Feminine' = [Extent9].[Name]) LIMIT 1) AS [C4]
                                                FROM ( SELECT 
                                                    [Project8].[MediaId] AS [MediaId], 
                                                    [Project8].[MediaTypeId] AS [MediaTypeId], 
                                                    [Project8].[Artist] AS [Artist], 
                                                    [Project8].[Title] AS [Title], 
                                                    [Project8].[Album] AS [Album], 
                                                    [Project8].[MediaCategoryId] AS [MediaCategoryId], 
                                                    [Project8].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
                                                    [Project8].[Preference] AS [Preference], 
                                                    [Project8].[Length] AS [Length], 
                                                    [Project8].[DownloadUrl] AS [DownloadUrl], 
                                                    [Project8].[BuyUrl] AS [BuyUrl], 
                                                    [Project8].[C1] AS [C1], 
                                                    [Project8].[C2] AS [C2], 
                                                    [Project8].[C3] AS [C3]
                                                    FROM ( SELECT 
                                                        [Project6].[MediaId] AS [MediaId], 
                                                        [Project6].[MediaTypeId] AS [MediaTypeId], 
                                                        [Project6].[Artist] AS [Artist], 
                                                        [Project6].[Title] AS [Title], 
                                                        [Project6].[Album] AS [Album], 
                                                        [Project6].[MediaCategoryId] AS [MediaCategoryId], 
                                                        [Project6].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
                                                        [Project6].[Preference] AS [Preference], 
                                                        [Project6].[Length] AS [Length], 
                                                        [Project6].[DownloadUrl] AS [DownloadUrl], 
                                                        [Project6].[BuyUrl] AS [BuyUrl], 
                                                        [Project6].[C1] AS [C1], 
                                                        [Project6].[C2] AS [C2], 
                                                        (SELECT 
                                                            [DbGetRatingValue]([Extent6].[Height], [Extent6].[Depth], @p__linq__3) AS [C1]
                                                            FROM  [MediaRatings] AS [Extent6]
                                                            INNER JOIN [RatingCategories] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent6].[RatingId] = [Extent7].[RatingId]
                                                            WHERE ([Project6].[MediaId] = [Extent6].[MediaId]) AND ('Emotional Masculine' = [Extent7].[Name]) LIMIT 1) AS [C3]
                                                        FROM ( SELECT 
                                                            [Project5].[MediaId] AS [MediaId], 
                                                            [Project5].[MediaTypeId] AS [MediaTypeId], 
                                                            [Project5].[Artist] AS [Artist], 
                                                            [Project5].[Title] AS [Title], 
                                                            [Project5].[Album] AS [Album], 
                                                            [Project5].[MediaCategoryId] AS [MediaCategoryId], 
                                                            [Project5].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
                                                            [Project5].[Preference] AS [Preference], 
                                                            [Project5].[Length] AS [Length], 
                                                            [Project5].[DownloadUrl] AS [DownloadUrl], 
                                                            [Project5].[BuyUrl] AS [BuyUrl], 
                                                            [Project5].[C1] AS [C1], 
                                                            [Project5].[C2] AS [C2]
                                                            FROM ( SELECT 
                                                                [Project3].[MediaId] AS [MediaId], 
                                                                [Project3].[MediaTypeId] AS [MediaTypeId], 
                                                                [Project3].[Artist] AS [Artist], 
                                                                [Project3].[Title] AS [Title], 
                                                                [Project3].[Album] AS [Album], 
                                                                [Project3].[MediaCategoryId] AS [MediaCategoryId], 
                                                                [Project3].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
                                                                [Project3].[Preference] AS [Preference], 
                                                                [Project3].[Length] AS [Length], 
                                                                [Project3].[DownloadUrl] AS [DownloadUrl], 
                                                                [Project3].[BuyUrl] AS [BuyUrl], 
                                                                [Project3].[C1] AS [C1], 
                                                                (SELECT 
                                                                    [DbGetRatingValue]([Extent4].[Height], [Extent4].[Depth], @p__linq__2) AS [C1]
                                                                    FROM  [MediaRatings] AS [Extent4]
                                                                    INNER JOIN [RatingCategories] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent4].[RatingId] = [Extent5].[RatingId]
                                                                    WHERE ([Project3].[MediaId] = [Extent4].[MediaId]) AND ('Physical Feminine' = [Extent5].[Name]) LIMIT 1) AS [C2]
                                                                FROM ( SELECT 
                                                                    [Project2].[MediaId] AS [MediaId], 
                                                                    [Project2].[MediaTypeId] AS [MediaTypeId], 
                                                                    [Project2].[Artist] AS [Artist], 
                                                                    [Project2].[Title] AS [Title], 
                                                                    [Project2].[Album] AS [Album], 
                                                                    [Project2].[MediaCategoryId] AS [MediaCategoryId], 
                                                                    [Project2].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
                                                                    [Project2].[Preference] AS [Preference], 
                                                                    [Project2].[Length] AS [Length], 
                                                                    [Project2].[DownloadUrl] AS [DownloadUrl], 
                                                                    [Project2].[BuyUrl] AS [BuyUrl], 
                                                                    [Project2].[C1] AS [C1]
                                                                    FROM ( SELECT 
                                                                        [Extent1].[MediaId] AS [MediaId], 
                                                                        [Extent1].[MediaTypeId] AS [MediaTypeId], 
                                                                        [Extent1].[Artist] AS [Artist], 
                                                                        [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
                                                                        [Extent1].[Album] AS [Album], 
                                                                        [Extent1].[MediaCategoryId] AS [MediaCategoryId], 
                                                                        [Extent1].[FileName] AS [FileName], 
                                                                        [Extent1].[Preference] AS [Preference], 
                                                                        [Extent1].[Length] AS [Length], 
                                                                        [Extent1].[DownloadUrl] AS [DownloadUrl], 
                                                                        [Extent1].[BuyUrl] AS [BuyUrl], 
                                                                        (SELECT 
                                                                            [DbGetRatingValue]([Extent2].[Height], [Extent2].[Depth], @p__linq__1) AS [C1]
                                                                            FROM  [MediaRatings] AS [Extent2]
                                                                            INNER JOIN [RatingCategories] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[RatingId] = [Extent3].[RatingId]
                                                                            WHERE ([Extent1].[MediaId] = [Extent2].[MediaId]) AND ('Physical Masculine' = [Extent3].[Name]) LIMIT 1) AS [C1]
                                                                        FROM [Media] AS [Extent1]
                                                                        WHERE [Extent1].[MediaTypeId] = @p__linq__0
                                                                    )  AS [Project2]
                                                                )  AS [Project3]
                                                            )  AS [Project5]
                                                        )  AS [Project6]
                                                    )  AS [Project8]
                                                )  AS [Project9]
                                            )  AS [Project11]
                                        )  AS [Project12]
                                    )  AS [Project14]
                                )  AS [Project15]
                            )  AS [Project17]
                        )  AS [Project18]
                    )  AS [Project20]
                )  AS [Project21]
            )  AS [Project23]
        )  AS [Project24]
    )  AS [Project26]
)  AS [Project27]
ORDER BY [Project27].[C4] DESC, [Project27].[Artist] ASC, [Project27].[Title] ASC


-- p__linq__0: '0' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__1: '0' (Type = Double, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__2: '0' (Type = Double, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__3: '0' (Type = Double, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__4: '0' (Type = Double, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__5: '0' (Type = Double, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__6: '0' (Type = Double, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__7: '0' (Type = Double, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__8: '0' (Type = Double, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__10: '' (Type = String)

-- p__linq__11: '0' (Type = Double, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__9: '' (Type = String)

-- Executing at 29/05/2015 5:41:19 PM -05:00

SQLite error (1): parser stack overflow
-- Failed in 39 ms with error: SQL logic error or missing database
parser stack overflow
```

This second query returns "no such function: Substring" error

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[MediaTypeId] AS [MediaTypeId], 
[Extent1].[MediaId] AS [MediaId], 
[Extent1].[Preference] AS [Preference]
FROM [Media] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ((((((((@p__linq__0 = 1) OR ([Extent1].[FileName] IS NOT NULL)) AND (([Extent1].[FileName] IS NOT NULL) OR ('' <> [Extent1].[DownloadUrl]))) AND (([Extent1].[Length] IS NULL) OR (((CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[EndPos] IS NOT NULL) THEN [Extent1].[EndPos] ELSE [Extent1].[Length] END) - (CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[StartPos] IS NOT NULL) THEN [Extent1].[StartPos] ELSE 0 END)) <= 720))) AND ((@p__linq__1 = 1) OR (0 = (CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM  [MediaRatings] AS [Extent2]
    INNER JOIN [RatingCategories] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[RatingId] = [Extent3].[RatingId]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[MediaId] = [Extent2].[MediaId]) AND ((('Fire' = [Extent3].[Name]) AND (([DbGetRatingValue]([Extent2].[Height], [Extent2].[Depth], 0)) >= 8.5)) OR (('Water' = [Extent3].[Name]) AND (([DbGetRatingValue]([Extent2].[Height], [Extent2].[Depth], 0)) >= 6)))
)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)))) AND ([Extent1].[MediaTypeId] = @p__linq__2)) AND (((CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT [Project2].[C1] AS [C1], [Project2].[Height] AS [Height], [Project2].[Depth] AS [Depth]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [DbGetRatingValue]([Extent4].[Height], [Extent4].[Depth], @p__linq__4) AS [C1], 
            [Extent4].[Height] AS [Height], 
            [Extent4].[Depth] AS [Depth]
            FROM  [MediaRatings] AS [Extent4]
            INNER JOIN [RatingCategories] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent4].[RatingId] = [Extent5].[RatingId]
            WHERE ([Extent1].[MediaId] = [Extent4].[MediaId]) AND ((CHARINDEX(@p__linq__3, [Extent5].[Name])) = 1)
        )  AS [Project2]
        ORDER BY [Project2].[C1] DESC LIMIT 1
    )  AS [Limit1]
    WHERE (((1 = @p__linq__6) AND ((([DbGetRatingValue]([Limit1].[Height], [Limit1].[Depth], @p__linq__5)) = @p__linq__7) OR (([DbGetRatingValue]([Limit1].[Height], [Limit1].[Depth], @p__linq__5) IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__7 IS NULL)))) OR ((0 = @p__linq__8) AND (([DbGetRatingValue]([Limit1].[Height], [Limit1].[Depth], @p__linq__5)) >= @p__linq__9))) OR (((2 = @p__linq__10) AND (([DbGetRatingValue]([Limit1].[Height], [Limit1].[Depth], @p__linq__5)) >= @p__linq__11)) AND (([DbGetRatingValue]([Limit1].[Height], [Limit1].[Depth], 0)) >= @p__linq__12))
)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = (CASE WHEN (2 <> @p__linq__13) THEN 1 WHEN (2 = @p__linq__13) THEN 0 END)) OR ((CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT [Project4].[Height] AS [Height], [Project4].[Depth] AS [Depth], [Project4].[C1] AS [C1]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent6].[Height] AS [Height], 
            [Extent6].[Depth] AS [Depth], 
            [DbGetRatingValue]([Extent6].[Height], [Extent6].[Depth], @p__linq__4) AS [C1]
            FROM  [MediaRatings] AS [Extent6]
            INNER JOIN [RatingCategories] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent6].[RatingId] = [Extent7].[RatingId]
            WHERE ([Extent1].[MediaId] = [Extent6].[MediaId]) AND ((CHARINDEX(@p__linq__3, [Extent7].[Name])) = 1)
        )  AS [Project4]
        ORDER BY [Project4].[C1] DESC LIMIT 1
    )  AS [Limit2]
    WHERE (((1 = @p__linq__6) AND ((([DbGetRatingValue]([Limit2].[Height], [Limit2].[Depth], @p__linq__5)) = @p__linq__7) OR (([DbGetRatingValue]([Limit2].[Height], [Limit2].[Depth], @p__linq__5) IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__7 IS NULL)))) OR ((0 = @p__linq__8) AND (([DbGetRatingValue]([Limit2].[Height], [Limit2].[Depth], @p__linq__5)) >= @p__linq__9))) OR (((2 = @p__linq__10) AND (([DbGetRatingValue]([Limit2].[Height], [Limit2].[Depth], @p__linq__5)) >= @p__linq__11)) AND (([DbGetRatingValue]([Limit2].[Height], [Limit2].[Depth], 0)) >= @p__linq__12))
)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END IS NULL) AND (CASE WHEN (2 <> @p__linq__13) THEN 1 WHEN (2 = @p__linq__13) THEN 0 END IS NULL)))) AND (((CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT [Project6].[C1] AS [C1], [Project6].[Height] AS [Height], [Project6].[Depth] AS [Depth]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [DbGetRatingValue]([Extent8].[Height], [Extent8].[Depth], @p__linq__15) AS [C1], 
            [Extent8].[Height] AS [Height], 
            [Extent8].[Depth] AS [Depth]
            FROM  [MediaRatings] AS [Extent8]
            INNER JOIN [RatingCategories] AS [Extent9] ON [Extent8].[RatingId] = [Extent9].[RatingId]
            WHERE ([Extent1].[MediaId] = [Extent8].[MediaId]) AND ((CHARINDEX(@p__linq__14, [Extent9].[Name])) = 1)
        )  AS [Project6]
        ORDER BY [Project6].[C1] DESC LIMIT 1
    )  AS [Limit3]
    WHERE (((1 = @p__linq__17) AND ((([DbGetRatingValue]([Limit3].[Height], [Limit3].[Depth], @p__linq__16)) = @p__linq__18) OR (([DbGetRatingValue]([Limit3].[Height], [Limit3].[Depth], @p__linq__16) IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__18 IS NULL)))) OR ((0 = @p__linq__19) AND (([DbGetRatingValue]([Limit3].[Height], [Limit3].[Depth], @p__linq__16)) >= @p__linq__20))) OR (((2 = @p__linq__21) AND (([DbGetRatingValue]([Limit3].[Height], [Limit3].[Depth], @p__linq__16)) >= @p__linq__22)) AND (([DbGetRatingValue]([Limit3].[Height], [Limit3].[Depth], 0)) >= @p__linq__23))
)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = (CASE WHEN (2 <> @p__linq__24) THEN 1 WHEN (2 = @p__linq__24) THEN 0 END)) OR ((CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT [Project8].[Height] AS [Height], [Project8].[Depth] AS [Depth], [Project8].[C1] AS [C1]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent10].[Height] AS [Height], 
            [Extent10].[Depth] AS [Depth], 
            [DbGetRatingValue]([Extent10].[Height], [Extent10].[Depth], @p__linq__15) AS [C1]
            FROM  [MediaRatings] AS [Extent10]
            INNER JOIN [RatingCategories] AS [Extent11] ON [Extent10].[RatingId] = [Extent11].[RatingId]
            WHERE ([Extent1].[MediaId] = [Extent10].[MediaId]) AND ((CHARINDEX(@p__linq__14, [Extent11].[Name])) = 1)
        )  AS [Project8]
        ORDER BY [Project8].[C1] DESC LIMIT 1
    )  AS [Limit4]
    WHERE (((1 = @p__linq__17) AND ((([DbGetRatingValue]([Limit4].[Height], [Limit4].[Depth], @p__linq__16)) = @p__linq__18) OR (([DbGetRatingValue]([Limit4].[Height], [Limit4].[Depth], @p__linq__16) IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__18 IS NULL)))) OR ((0 = @p__linq__19) AND (([DbGetRatingValue]([Limit4].[Height], [Limit4].[Depth], @p__linq__16)) >= @p__linq__20))) OR (((2 = @p__linq__21) AND (([DbGetRatingValue]([Limit4].[Height], [Limit4].[Depth], @p__linq__16)) >= @p__linq__22)) AND (([DbGetRatingValue]([Limit4].[Height], [Limit4].[Depth], 0)) >= @p__linq__23))
)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END IS NULL) AND (CASE WHEN (2 <> @p__linq__24) THEN 1 WHEN (2 = @p__linq__24) THEN 0 END IS NULL)))) AND ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM  [MediaRatings] AS [Extent12]
    INNER JOIN [RatingCategories] AS [Extent13] ON [Extent12].[RatingId] = [Extent13].[RatingId]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[MediaId] = [Extent12].[MediaId]) AND ((((((CHARINDEX(Substring(@p__linq__26, 1 + 1, (LENGTH(@p__linq__26)) - 1), [Extent13].[Name])) <> 1) AND (0 = [Extent13].[Custom])) AND ('Egoless' <> [Extent13].[Name])) AND ('Love' <> [Extent13].[Name])) AND ((2 = @p__linq__27) AND (([DbGetRatingValue]([Extent12].[Height], [Extent12].[Depth], @p__linq__25)) >= @p__linq__28)))
))


-- p__linq__0: 'True' (Type = Boolean, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__1: 'False' (Type = Boolean, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__2: '0' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__3: 'Emotional' (Type = String)

-- p__linq__4: '0' (Type = Double, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__6: '0' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__5: '0' (Type = Double, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__7: '6.7' (Type = Double)

-- p__linq__8: '0' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__9: '6.7' (Type = Double)

-- p__linq__10: '0' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__11: '6.7' (Type = Double)

-- p__linq__12: '6.7' (Type = Double)

-- p__linq__13: '0' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__14: 'Emotional' (Type = String)

-- p__linq__15: '0' (Type = Double, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__17: '2' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__16: '0' (Type = Double, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__18: '7.5' (Type = Double)

-- p__linq__19: '2' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__20: '7.5' (Type = Double)

-- p__linq__21: '2' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__22: '7.5' (Type = Double)

-- p__linq__23: '7.5' (Type = Double)

-- p__linq__24: '2' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__26: '!Emotional' (Type = String)

-- p__linq__27: '2' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__25: '0' (Type = Double, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__28: '8' (Type = Double)

-- Executing at 29/05/2015 5:36:36 PM -05:00

SQLite error (1): no such function: Substring
-- Failed in 103 ms with error: SQL logic error or missing database
no such function: Substring
```

This seems to be a bug in the SQL parser as the correct function is substr, not substring

Is there any way to fix these errors?

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd error is due to a bug with Substring generating SUBSTRING instead of SUBSTR.

Here's a way to fix this bug.

In your database model, add this code right before EntityContainer

```
<Function Name="substr" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo" ReturnType="nvarchar">
  <Parameter Name="text" Type="nvarchar" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="startPos" Type="int" Mode="In" />
</Function>
```

In your context class (create a partial class next to it), add this code

```
[DbFunction("MyModel.Store", "substr")]
public string SubStr(string text, int startPos) {
    return text.Substring(startPos);
}
```

In your code, call Substring in this way

```
context.SubStr(text, startpos)
```

It will now properly map to the SUBSTR function instead of SUBSTRING! It's like mapping a User Defined Function, except that we map to an existing standard function.

This doesn't resolve the first error though.